# iPhone - iScroll doesn't work when when VoiceOver is on

Tags: iphone, cordova, wai-aria, voiceover, iscroll

I have a Cordova Mobile application which uses iScroll plugin. To my surprise scroll doesn't work when I run the app in VoiceOver mode (three finger swipe up/down gesture). It just reads page 1 of 1 even if the content is existing for more than 2 pages.

Are there any role attributes to make page to scroll ? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that iScroll is using transform CSS property for scrolling.
I was able to resolve this issue. 
May be you can also try the same.

1. Add below style to your parent div

-webkit-overflow-scrolling : touch

2. There is a phone gap plugin to listen for VoiceOver on/off https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-mobile-accessibility

   // Define a persistent callback method to handle the event
   function onScreenReaderStatusChanged(info) {
       if (info && typeof info.isScreenReaderRunning !== "undefined") {
           if (info.isScreenReaderRunning) {
               console.log("Screen reader: ON");
               // Do something to improve the behavior of the application while a screen reader is active.
           } else {
               console.log("Screen reader: OFF");
           }
       }
   }

   // Register the callback method to handle the event
   **window.addEventListener(MobileAccessibilityNotifications.SCREEN_READER_STATUS_CHANGED, onScreenReaderStatusChanged, false);**

On voiceover **ON** event you can destroy iScroll(or make useTransform property to false).
On voiceover **OFF** you can re-initiate the iScroll.

Let me know if it works.